# Form image submit nopt working in Internet Explorer, submit redirects to index.php without passing elements

Tags: php, forms

I have the following form to upload images of my products, this works great in Firefox and Chrome, but in Internet Explorer images are NOT uploaded and instead of uploading images, I am being redirected to my www.myhomepage.com/index.php instead of submitting the form elements and remaining in the same url which in Chrome is something like: /index.php?view=user&task=editi&productid=3872, which is the link I have in firefox address bar after submitting the form.

I think some form field is not passed to internet explorer but I cant find the reason.

this is the code of the form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="ImageForm" id="ImageForm"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="botones_form" style="width:100%; float:right;">
<input name="files" type="file" id="files" class="files" />

</div>
<input class="save" type="submit" name="boton" value="<?php echo JText::_( 'Upload Images' ); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="<?php echo $option; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="parent" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="save" />
<input type="hidden" name="controller" value="images" />

</form>
```

Do you see anything wrong with this code? What could be the problem? I am no programmer, so I dont know if you need more details in order to help me, but please feel free to ask more code of the php file where the form is located or code of any called controller...

Comment: If you want the query string (part of url after `?`) to appear in the url, you need to specify that part in the `action` attribute of the `<form>` tag.

Comment: well, actually my problem is not the query string not appearing in URL, but the fact that I cant upload images, if i click submit, I am redirected to mysite.com/index.php instead of uploading the image. And this works in firefox and chrome, do you know any solution PLEASE?

Comment: Given this form, all browsers will "redirect" to index.php. If you put something like `var_dump($_FILES)` in index.php, all 3 main browsers should send the same data.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, so you mean I should try to add this line anywhere in index.php inside <?php ......... ?> ?

Comment: do you need more details? perhaps I can post the entire code of the php file?

Comment: Show the _relevant_ parts of the script that processes the uploaded data.